# What is the phrase "Above all the hunt" translated into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

I'm designing a sigil for my special forces team in a sci-fi book I'm writing, and without making this a 10,000 word post with backstory, the phrase on the sigil is "Above all, the hunt". Google and every other translation site out there does literal word for word translation, and I know that is not how Latin works or pretty much how any language translated into another works, so I'm lost as to what it could be. Any help?

Comment: As @Joonas Ilmavirta suggests, this question would be more likely to get an answer if you showed that you had looked in an online dictionary or made an effort beyond just Google Translate. (Online Latin dictionaries can often be frustrating! But just for future reference, the good-faith effort helps.)

Comment: Have you tried translating it yourself, instead of just coming here to ask?

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest "venatio supra omnia".
There are many ways to translate "above all", and what I chose is a literal one.

To get started with future requests, you can look at an online Latin dictionary.
[You can find a list in our dictionary list question.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79)
If you type in "hunt", you will get several hunting-related words in Latin.
You can read their English translations and decide which word would have the most suitable tone for your use even if you can't put words together into sentences.
For hunting the case is pretty clear, but it's not so for all words.
If you have some suitable words together and maybe a Google translation, you can give them in your question; sometimes such background work really helps, and most importantly it shows your own effort.
Sometimes short phrases are the hardest ones to translate well, so it might help to give several ways to express your sentence in English and explain what you want to say.

Your translation request was simple enough, but I just wanted to give some advice to you (and others who end up reading this) to make things run smoothly when help is needed again.