# How would you translate 'To hunt is to live' into Latin?

Tags: translation-check

I want to translate the motto "To hunt is to live" to Latin.
The motto is for a hunting club.

The translation I have arrived at is: *Venari est vivere*. Is this a correct translation? If not, how could it be improved?

Comment: Hi emilw, please take a look at [this question about how to ask translation questions](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/what-do-we-do-with-translation-requests): since this isn't just a translation service, you need to show at least some evidence of effort (online dictionaries, etc.), which should be accessible even to someone who has never studied Latin. (Pro tip: don't use Google Translate!)

Comment: We'd be more than happy to answer more specific questions, such as "Is X or Y a better word for 'to hunt'" or "What is the best way to say 'to X is to Y' in Latin?"

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, brianpck. Please forgive my brief, "translation service" style question. I've tried my hand with the translation myself, however, I have very little experience with translating latin.

The translation I have arrived at is: 'Venari est vivere'. It seems simple, but I know how difficult translating English into Latin can be! Does this seem like a correct translation?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I took the liberty of editing your question a little (a more specific tag and including the English motto in the text body), but feel free to re-edit. You might also want to take a look at [an older question about a similar phrase](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/479/79).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your translation is entirely correct! You have two infinitives, *venari* and *vivere*, which are both idiomatic. The finite verb *est* "is" is used to connect the two, just as in English, which is also idiomatic.

P.S. To novice learners of Latin, *venari* might seem wrong, but it's not. It is the passive infinitive, because *venari* is a deponent, which means that hardly has any active forms at all, and that its passive forms are generally translated as if they were active.

Comment: Could not the verb go at the end, to make *"venari vivere est"*? Is there a reason to prefer placing verb in the middle?

Comment: @JamesK Both positions are possible. I don't know if there is a reason to prefer one over the other. That would make an interesting question.

Comment: Other mottoes of a similar form have the verb in the middle, e.g. *laborare est orare* (the motto of Benedictine monks). This doesn't make it correct, of course, but it might be a nice reference to make.

Comment: @lonesomeday The more common phrase is *ora et labora*--I couldn't find an original Benedictine document that has *orare est laborare*, though I agree with your point. Note a similar counter-example, though, from St. Paul: *vivere Christus est.*

Answer (score 1):

> *[Praedari](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praedari) est vivere.*

Wiktionary also appears to condone the form [*praedare*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praedare), although this could be an error.

This is not an authoritative answer. It’s just how I would say it.

Comment: [*praedor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpraedor) usually translates as "to make booty, to plunder, spoil, rob": do you have a particular reason for suggesting it as "to hunt"?